# Gauging Tag Popularity

Tags: support, tags

Is it possible to gauge the popularity of a particular tag?  For example, can I see how much more or less popular the tag [java] is than [c++] over the last week on Stack Overflow?  If so, how?

Comment: How about one of these http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=popular+tag

Comment: What you you mean by popularity?  Number of questions, answers, posts, votes, views, upvotes?

Comment: Yes.  Any and/or all of those.

Comment: @rene - that's about right!

Comment: @Andy So which of those do you equate with popularity.  If you want it to incorporate multiple variables, then you need to decide how much weight to give each one.

Comment: @Servy - Agreed!  My apologies as I simply didn't know where to start on this one, hence the vagueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of these type of questions can be answerd by :

- picking an existing query from [The Stack Exchange DataExplorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=popular+tag)
- by creating a query yourself (using Microsoft Sql dialect) and using the [schema description of all tables and its functional meaning provided in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100)

Comment: And once you create it, post it here, so people can find it. D: